# Why not say it explicitly? "Product recommendation questions aren't allowed here."

Tags: discussion, questions, equipment-recommendations

Product recommendation questions are appearing everyday. They are downvoted but they're still there, making the list a bit messy.

I know, you know... But what about folks who come to this site via a Google search? They don't understand how SE works and think this site could help them to decide.

The current question form contains a few hints:

> What's your photography question? Be specific.
>   Is your question about photography?
>   We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
>   Provide details. Share your research.
>   If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.

Shouldn't it also contain a higly visible warning: "**Please don't ask here what product/brand to choose. Use XXX, YYY or ZZZ sites instead?**"

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in that these questions appear daily.

However, be aware that they tend to get flagged and later removed.

That being said, you can ask a *good* product/brand question. For example:

- [What is good protection for outside timelapse? (During rain/thunderstorm)](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/64149/what-is-good-protection-for-outside-timelapse-during-rain-thunderstorm)
- [Is there any significant difference between Nikon and Canon?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-nikon-and-canon)
- [How do Cokin and Lee filter systems compare to each other?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2327/how-do-cokin-and-lee-filter-systems-compare-to-each-other)
- [Of course a good search shows good ones](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=[equipment-recommendation]%20hasaccepted%3ayes)

Also, take a look at a question that I raised not too long ago: [Do we scare off new users?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4729/do-we-scare-off-new-users) and [mattdm](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm) as recommended starting a [photo-shopping](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4732/38156) SE.

We aren't anti-brand, but we are anti-bad-research. Normally, product recommendations come in that are so vague and we don't know what a person really wants. In order to prevent giving a bad recommendation or start a flame war, we just close them.

Oh, and one more link: [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) This is normally posted with bad product recommendation questions. I think that will clear most things up.

Comment: I like the point that these question are _usually_ low quality ones. But... aren't the product recommendation questions closed because they become very fast **obsolete** (whatever good they are)? Even the last link you posted says so. Moreover, answers tend to be **opinion based** (biased) - a lifetime Canon user would hardly recommend something from Nikon.